# how to use to action in a function fired by a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, event-handling, action

I keep getting the error "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined" because of the action fired in my onClick event. I want the action to fire with a piece of state from the store to make an AJAX request with it.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { fetchInfo } from "../actions";

// Here we take in the passed in props from the FoodList component and render
// the dishes for the inputted ingredients

class Recipe extends Component {

  renderFood(food) {
    return (
      <div className="food-container">
        {food.map(function(recipe) {
          return (
            <div
              className="indiv-recipe"
              style={{
                backgroundImage: "url(" + recipe.image + ")"
              }}
              onClick={() => this.props.fetchInfo(recipe.id)}
            >
              <div id="recipe-title"> {recipe.title}</div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.foods.map(this.renderFood)}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchInfo }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Recipe);
```

Comment: This is a guess, but have you tried arrow notation instead of `function`? I'm not sure `function` binds to `this` by default. If you can't use arrows, you could curry the `this` in.

Comment: I tried the arrow function but that didn't work. What do you mean by curry?

Comment: If changing `function(recipe) {...}` to `(recipe) => { ... }` didn't work, the problem might not be with binding with `this`; what else could it be? Hmm. By curry I meant: changing `function(recipe) { ... }` to `function (this_) { return function(recipe) { ... }}(this)` and using `this_.props.fetchInfo` instead of `this.props.fetchInfo`.

Comment: i think you should omit the `this.props` before `fetchInfo` because this has nothing to do with the props - you're importing it from actions

Comment: It turns out that {this.props.foods.map(this.renderFood)} needed to be switched to {this.props.foods.map(this.renderFood, this)}. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You are just missing this in both map's, either change both to an arrow function or pass it as a second parameter when calling map.